# How can I interpret my result of knn and of decision tree?

Tags: python, decision-tree, knn

Details about my goal:
I am using the IMDb data and Youtube movie trailer data to predict movie's gross.
Specifically, I am using 'range', 'gross', 'budget','imdb_score','views','rating' to make classification.

So, I ran through KNN and Decision Tree 1) to predict movie's success, and also to 2) know which machine learning would be more accurate.

but the problem is, my knn result for

```
feature_columns = ['range', 'gross', 'budget','imdb_score','views','rating']
X = df2[feature_columns].values
y = df2['range'].values

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, metric='euclidean')
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

ended up with an Accuracy of our model is equal 94.0 %.
with

```
array([[ 4,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 27,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1, 20,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  7]])
```

[KNN pairplot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5oQC.png)

and for decision tree,

```
feature_cols = ["budget","imdb_score","views","rating"]
y = df2.range
X = df2[feature_cols]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy") #Default criterion is gini index, If you want to use gini index just delete criterion

clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train) #Training

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test) #Make a prediction

print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

ended up with an Accuracy: 0.48333333333333334

```
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data,  
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True,feature_names = feature_cols,class_names=["0","1","2","3"]) ##Change class i named 0, and 1 since i only have to class
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
graph.write_png('house.png') #will saved to your default location. in coolab it is content folder 
Image(graph.create_png())
```

[Decision Tree result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmiQG.jpg)

**My question is,
1) are my results reflective of my subject? The fact that KNN accuracy is 94% and Decision Tree of 48% is confusing. I thought accuracy of decision tree would be higher.
2) I am especially unsure if my column features for both KNN and Decision Tree are the same, to reflect the same result. Had my features edited differently?**

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

In KNN, you give the target column **range** in the training data too so the accuracy of the model is very hight when compared to decision tree.

You missed the gross feature in the training data of decision tree.
So You should not compare the performance of these two algorithm since they have different training data .Try once again with same training data for both the algorithm

**Note:** Please mention what is meant by gross and range